# When should one manually create Channels?

Tags: netty, channel

When, if ever, does netty create new Channels? Or are the only Channels in existence those created explicitly by the appllication?

Answer (score 0):

If you study the different "bootstrap" classes [here](http://static.netty.io/3.6/api/), you will see that `ClientBootstrap` and `ConnectionlessBootstrap` creates channels on invocation of the `bind()` and `connect()`methods. A `Serverbootstrap`, on the other hand, creates a channel when a remote client connects to the local server address/port.

Think in "active" and "passive" terms. A client is active in the sense that it actively, or explicitly, connects to a remote server or peer. A server is passive since it lazily waits for  incoming connections from remote clients or peers--and creates child channels for each of them.